# Dynamically add classes to Guice through reflection

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guice

Is it possible with Guice (and even in Java in general) to iterate over all classes in a particular package and add them to Guice?

The underlying problem: I'd like to be able to route all traffic to /admin/* to a single servlet which redirects accordingly. Then I'd like to be able to just add servlets to the same package and have them get picked up automatically. E.g. If I navigate to /admin/showCompanyDetails, I'd like that to redirect to a servlet called showCompanyDetails.java in the admin package.

Furthermore, I'd like this to work in such a way that all I have to do to add further admin functions is to drop a new class into the admin package. I.e. No factory methods to update and no containers to add to.

So far, the closest I've come is to have the redirect servlet create a Guice injector with a module that contains all the admin servlets. But as I said, I'd like to avoid having to update a Guice module.

Also, I'd like this to be possible in AppEngine.

And I want a pony.

Comment: Yeah, you do want a pony.  In other words, ewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww.

Comment: If you walk the classpath, then you can evaluate all class and jar files. However, its much cleaner to use the Guice servlet extension and make explicit bindings.

Comment: @ben Is it bad practice to use convention-based configuration of IoC containers in Java? The reason I asked the question is because it is common in C#. Most of the major containers support some form of auto-registration.

Comment: @KyleBaley It was very common, but its going out of fashion. This is because auto-magic is confusing with the plethora of frameworks, making it harder to debug when you don't know the internals in a large project. Explicit, simple to understand libraries are preferred. A ServletModule per package is very simple and obvious.

Answer (score -1):

There are some possibilities:

- Use Servlet 3 `@WebServlet` annotations on your servlet classes, so they get picked up by a Servlet 3 web container. Then you can use Guice to inject dependencies, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=678) for an example.
- Use [guice-automatic-injection](https://github.com/manzke/guice-automatic-injection/) to bind your servlet classes in your classpath (they must contain their path similar to Servlet 3 via annotations or provide an accessor for it). Then you can create a Guice servlet module which retrieves all those servlets from Guice and registers them as servlets to their provided paths.

Both ways may be usable in AppEngine, but I haven't got experience with it.

Getting a pony is easy if you use just `Object` as its base class ;p